# Is PHP's "Reflection" class included by default in all PHP 5+ installs?

Tags: php

I know some classes listed on PHP.net say "PHP 5+" but are actually contained in optional packages (like PECL). Is the Reflection class a default one that my code is guaranteed to have on any PHP 5 installation?

Comment: Looking in the requirements/installation notes for any extension should tell you:  in the case of Reflection `There is no installation needed to use these functions; they are part of the PHP core.`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks. I read them and somehow missed it. wonky brain.

Comment: @MarkBaker: But from which PHP version though? The docs aren't clear about this (at least, from what I can see). [This 3v4l.org test](http://3v4l.org/s2YlM) however shows as them being available only since PHP 5.1.2.

Comment: @AmalMurali that's not good if true. any way to be sure? what is 3v4l?

Comment: However, if Reflection wasn't in those earlier versions, I'd have expected an error with `$class = new ReflectionClass('ReflectionClass');`, not simply a false return from the `getExtensionName()` call.... http://3v4l.org/mNADl

Comment: @MarkBaker: Ah, you're right. [This one](http://3v4l.org/0C41L) actually proves it. I blindly copy pasted an example from the docs. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @DonRhummy: That wasn't true. 3v4l is just an online codepad that allows you to execute PHP code in 100+ versions.

Comment: I suspect the 5.1.2 getExtensionName() returning false is related to `Added reflection constants as class constants. (Johannes)` in the 5.1.2 changelog

Comment: However, prior to 5.3.0 it was possible to explicitly disable Reflection when building from source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PHP 5 Reflection Intro: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.installation.php

"PHP 5 comes with a complete reflection API..."

"There is no installation needed to use these functions; they are part of the PHP core."

Comment: Thanks. somehow I missed that.

Comment: @DonRhummy: Looks like it's available all versions since **PHP 5.1.2**: http://3v4l.org/s2YlM